# Названия таблиц объекта SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть необходимость получать название объектов SQLAlchemy. 
Можно это сделать так: `db.metadata.tables.keys()`, и результат тот что нужен - названия таблиц.

Однако, задача стоит чуть более трудная: я хочу имея ключ на входе, пройтись по списку либо словарю, и получить ту таблицу, название которой так или иначе совпадает с ключом.

```
@bp.route('/post', methods=['PUT'])
@UserPermission()
def post():
    tables = list(db.metadata.tables.keys())
    url = request.form['keyword']

    return render_template(index/index.html, items=items)
```

Я хочу в items передать результат выборку по keyword. Вышеизложенный способ возвращает AttributeError:

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае сработало так:

```
@bp.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
@UserPermission()
def post():
    request_url = request.form['url']
    baselist = [User, Organisation, Contact, Project, Activity, Invoice]
    for i in baselist:
        if str(i.__tablename__) == str(request_url.split('/')[-1][:-1]):
```

Было бы круто, не держать такой список, а получать выборку импортов.